# videomixing decodebin streams

Tags: python, gstreamer

I've been breaking my head for days trying to mix video streams with gstreamer in python.

I've first tried to use playbin2, but it seems to be impossible to use playbin2 with videomixer. I've then tried to do the same thing with decodebin. I've managed to do it using a gstreamer pipeline, but no way to make it work in python. Does someone know how to translate this to python code?

```
gst-launch filesrc location=test01.mpg ! decodebin ! \
videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=640, height=480 ! videobox alpha=0.5 left=-640 ! \
videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! \
xvimagesink filesrc location=test02.mpg ! decodebin ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=640, height=480 ! videobox left=-600 ! \
mix.
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a usefull link for this:

http://wiki.pitivi.org/wiki/PyGST_Tutorial

The chapter 5 of the tutorial illustrates how could this be achieved...

A little tip for anyone starting with a gstreamer project: if you have a choice, I would suggest to write your application in C and not in python, as the python API is very incomplete...